# How to define scope of Single Sign On?

Tags: asp.net, .net, single-sign-on, saml

If you create an SSO SAML web based solution that works within your company, what happens when another company wants to integrate with you?  Do they need to conform to your interface or you to theirs?

What if the other company is not using a SAML based SSO solution?

If your company has written the solution in .NET, does that restrict expansion of the SSO solution (windows based, integrating with other companies)?

Am I correct in saying that if a web based solution is built, it will not work for Windows and vice versa?  In other words, if you want to support Windows and web based, two solutions must be provided?

Answer (score 1):

SAML is a protocol so if both sides conform it will work.

You swop configuration details via metadata exchange.

If you wrote a SAML web based solution in .NET , you probably used ADFS to provide the SAML piece or used a 3rd party SAML stack?

As long as it supports SAML in some way, the fact that it is .NET is irrelevant.